# Creating a new type

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In delphi I would like to create a new type (Machine) that copies TShape. Mostly due to wanting to add more procedures and functions. For example i could do something like this

```
Machine.type('402')
```

and it would draw the shape, but with a defined Height / width.
and like this

```
Machine.before('Microclean');
```

and it would know where to put the shape.

So ..two part question.
1. Is making a new type sound like what i need?
2. How do i make a new blank type, Thus as its own unit and can add my new procedures to it?

thanks
Glen

Comment: Why `Machine.type('402')` and not `Machine.type(402)` ?  Why string instead of number ? What if someone calls `Machine.type('Zebra')` ?

Comment: it was an example, but 402 is the name of the machine in the db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need a new class that inherits from TShape:

```
TMachine = class(TShape)
public
  procedure MyType(const AType: string);
  procedure Before(const ABfore: string);
end;
```

You could then provide code for the two procedures.

Note that you cant use type for a procedure name - that is a reserved word. Also it is a Delphi convention (but not a requirement) to prefix class names with a 'T'

Comment: @bummi - why not? Make those procedures property-setters if u wish. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Properties#Property_Access

Comment: Also ur original question does not show properties. Properties should be used as `Machine.MyType := 402;`

Comment: truthfully i am new to making own classes,  so best way i really dont know.. just trying a way and see where it goes from there. I picked procedures cause once it gets the type '402' , it will have to select the width / height from a data base.

Comment: @Keith Miller  When i add that, it says TShape is undeclared? Something in the uses i must add?  nm, it was extctrls :D